# $2\cos^2(3x)+5\cos(3x)−3<0$ solving for inequality

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$2\cos^2(3x)+5\cos(3x)−3<0$

For this question, I replaced $\cos(3x)$ by k which produced

$2k^2+5k−3<0$

Through factoring the left hand side I got

$(k+3)(2k-1)<0$

$0$ at $k=-3, 1/2$

Since the range of the cosine function is $[-1,1]$, $k=-3$ is extraneous

Equating  $1/2$ to $\cos(3x)$, I got $x=\pi/9$

I know I need to find more values of $x$. However, I am not sure how to.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

As $\cos3x+3\ge3-1>0,$

We need $\cos3x<1/2=\cos\pi/3$

Now the opposite
$\cos3x\ge1/2\implies2n\pi-\pi/3\le3x\le2n\pi+\pi/3$ where $n$ is any integer